# How to express difference between classes

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs, phrases

I want to say

> "They belong to different classes."

Is it right to say

> "They differ in class." ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Your first sentence could mean many things, because *class* has different meanings. Could you add more context?

Comment: It's clear that class is being used to mean category, or some kind of category. I don't think it matters which (e.g., grade in school, socio-economic level, or "type" in general), in order to be able to answer the question. It should be re-opened so that it can be answered.

Comment: Both are grammatical, and the meaning of the second is synonymous with that of the first.

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is perfectly fine for **some** meanings of *class* but not others. The first sentence uses *class* to refer to a grouping, as a [count noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun).

However, the second sentence only works if *class* is also an intrinsic quality (social standing, technical complexity, biological taxonomy, etc).

Comment: This looks fairly reasonable. Would you mind editing the question somewhat to clear up the understanding of it that led you to be able to answer it?